# C# code to convert this XAML label content binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi I have a label which is binded to a resource file. The label is as follows:

```
<Label Name="LabelName" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.LabelName}" />
```

How would I convert this to C# code so I can generate the label dynamically?

I tried doing

```
LabelName.SetBinding(ContentProperty, "{x:Static p:Resources.LabelName}");
```

but the label content shows up blank on the screen.

Thank you.

Comment: Where xmlns:local = "clr-namespace:WPFLocalization" 
            xmlns:p="clr-namespace:WPFLocalization.Properties"

Comment: `Content="{x:Static p:Resources.LabelName}"` is not a binding, but just a plain assignment.

Comment: _"so I can generate the label dynamically?"_ -- you're already on the wrong track. You should not be generating the label dynamically; you should be using templating or similar to have WPF generate the label dynamically on your behalf, and then you can use the same XAML syntax to set the property as you already are. It's not possible to provide a _good_ answer with so little context; at the moment, the best that can be done is to answer your question literally, which frankly isn't the answer you _need_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LabelName.Content = WPFLocalization.Properties.Resources.LabelName;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. The p library is as follows: xmlns:p="clr-namespace:WPFLocalization.Properties" What is the syntax for referencing to the p library?

Comment: @John How do you usually refer to a class when you know what namespace it's in?